# If two devices both require 12V 2A power can I use a 12V 4A power supply to power them both?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, dc, amperage

The question title says it all really: I have two devices that both require a 12V 2A power supply, so I'm assuming that I can I just use a **single** 12V 4A power supply to power them both?

I'm also assuming that a 24V 2A power supply would **NOT** work in the same way?

Any explanations as to why the two above assumptions are correct or not would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if this is a very basic question but I'm fairly new to electronics and just looking for a place where I can ask questions and learn from others. Thanks.

Comment: Post a circuit diagram. If the devices are connected in parallel you need more current; if they're in series you need more voltage.

Comment: What devices they are and should they be electrically isolated from each other?

Comment: One is an external USB hard drive, and the other is an Android TV box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, yes.

Devices in parallel share the voltage, not the current.

Devices in series share the current, not the voltage. The only way to connect them in series is to connect the positive of one to the ground of the other, and with variable current devices that's not going to end up good.

Connecting two DC devices in parallel with a single 12V 4A supply is like connecting two mains power devices to the same power strip. They both see the same voltage but take whatever current they need.

There can be issues with supply quality or possibly noise but generally if you have a decent supply then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Just as a follow-up question (if I may). I hear a lot about devices "taking whatever current they need" — could you possibly help me understand how an electronic device knows what current it "needs". What stops it from taking the maximum current that the power supply is capable of?

Comment: That's a bit complicated. The simplest answer is Ohms Law. Current = Voltage / Resistance. It's relative. But complex devices draw different currents depending on what part of it is on or off. A hard drive has a motor that draws more when the motor spins for example. Any device has multiple parts and each part has hundreds of transistors etc etc.

Comment: So the device isn't "taking" the current in an active sense; the device is just a passive electrical component. It's more a case of the input current flowing through the device at a rate determined by the physical resistance of the circuitry on the device?

Comment: That's not a bad way of putting it. Though it is active because the circuitry can change what's on or off at various times.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assuming that I can I just use a single 12V 4A power supply to power them both?

Quick answer: **Yes**

By theory, components connected in parallel will utilize the same amount of voltage while drawing their respective current needs. The source must have a rating that can supply the overall current requirement of the system.

On this case, it was mentioned that it was a hard drive and a TV Box so they must be connected in parallel.

Hard drive will utilize 12 volts from the source and will draw 2 Amperes of current and the TV Box will also utilize 12 volts from the source while drawing 2 Amperes as well. Therefore, a 12 Volts, 4 Amperes will suffice.

> I'm also assuming that a 24V 2A power supply would NOT work in the same way?

Quick answer: **Yes**

We will go back to the statement that your Hard drive and TV Box will be connected to the source in parallel.

In this case, each of them will utilize 24 Volts available from the source. This will turn very bad because **it can cook up the electronics inside!**

Both devices will never operate, damaged, and at worst case scenario, can pose an electrical hazard that might result in injuries.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your question on the 24V 2A option. It wont work in your case, but conceptually it could work if the two loads were closely matched in terms of power consumption and were simple like resistor (or incandescent globe). In that case each would run with only 12V across it. The reason for simple is the behaviour of the two load need to match even during power up. A modern electronic loads (like switched mode power supplies) will not behave so simply.

Older mains power Christmas tree lights did exactly this but not with 2 loads but dozens in series, each bulb was rated at far less than the mains voltage. They were a pain because a single blown globe resulted in the whole string losing power.

Answer (score 1):

Current is typically thought of as being 'drawn' from the power supply by a load, at least when it is some kind of active electronic device like a USB hard drive or Android box.

Only in the case of, say, a totally passive element like a resistor or incandescent light bulb (which is just a resistor that gets white hot) is it really conceptually appropriate to imagine voltage forcing current through the load.

However, current is what actually does work, generates heat, consumes energy.  Voltage acts as multiplier for this - 5V at 1A is 5W of power, 10V at 1A is 10W of power - but in the absence of current flow, there is no work being done.

Intuitively, this means that you can think of the current an active electronic device draws as the power it is consuming to function. It isn't that an electronic device knows what current it 'needs' and stops at a certain point, it is simply consuming current at the rate required to function.

You wouldn't ask how a car 'knows' the gasoline flow rate it needs, or what stops it from taking the maximum amount of fuel it can possibly burn, right?  Just like the car, electronic devices are just consuming energy at a particular rate (power) to do whatever it is they need to do at a given moment.

The current rating of a power supply is a maximum rating.  A 12V 4A power supply isn't going to try to push 4A into anything.  From the load's point of view, there is no difference between a 12V 1A power supply or a 12V 100A power supply, since as long as the voltage is the same, it will consume power/draw current no differently from one or the other.  The current spec is simply saying that ***up to*** that current can be drawn from the power supply.

So there is no 'knowing when to stop' because the current rating is merely a maximum, not something that actually impacts the current a given load (at a constant voltage).

Returning to the car analogy, a car might be rated for 200HP, but this doesn't mean it will constantly be generating this much power.  It can generate UP TO that much if you floor it and the RPM is in the right spot, but it isn't going to force you to drive around at full power all the time.  And neither will a power supply.

Now, even active devices expect a certain voltage range as voltage will force more or less current through them just like a passive resistor, but they will just dissipate this as heat or will have internal switch mode regulators that will make them draw less current at a higher voltage because they really only care about the power they need.  More voltage means you can get the same power while drawing less current.

On the other hand, active devices connected in series will not share the voltage.  And they will not be able to consume the amount of current they individually want.  Both devices will see an uneven portion of the voltage depending on what they are doing.

Also note that the hard drive and android box current ratings are also maximums - it is saying that they can require up to 2A at 12V.  But they almost certainly do not actually draw 2A all the time.  The hard drive might briefly draw this when spinning up, but it will draw a fair bit less once it is spinning and idle.  The Android box will draw power dynamically depending on the CPU power state and processing demand.

Regardless, current ratings for power supplies and devices are typically maximums (that can be provided, or that might be required depending on if it is the power supply or the device), but they will use what they need.  Think of current as being consumed like a fuel.

Comment: "it is simply consuming current at the rate required to function" – this still doesn't make sense to me. This statement implies that the device knows what its function is; like it has some sort of awareness of what it's doing. And the car analogy doesn't really compare because the driver of the car is pushing the fuel through with the accelerator - the car isn't taking it of it's own accord.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, you can power both with a 12V 4A supply and NO, you can't use 24V 2A supply, it will fry everything most likely.

Long answer: If one or both devices is sensitive to noise (eg an audio amplifier), powering two devices from the same supply could create noise that intereferes with normal operation (eg hum in speakers). But operation would be safe as long as you are sure demand for current never exceeds 4 amps. If one or both devices can peak at any value higher than 2A then you will have problems. If 2A is their peak current rating, you are safe with the 12V 4A supply. But if the devices peak at a higher value, then your supply must be able to supply both at their peak value at the same time (eg if one peaks at 2.5A and the other at 3A but both have a nominal current of 2A, your supply must be able to give 2.5A + 3A = 5.5A.

24V propably exceeds the voltage the devices are rated for so it would break everything with nasty sparks and smoke. But even if your devices can handle 24V too, 2A in total is **still NOT enough**